# AJAX overwritting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently using AJAX for live submit a post which is then appended to a list. The problem I am having is when I submit a post more than once, AJAX overwrites the previous posts submitted.

```
var data = $("#form_write_post").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#form_write_post").attr("action"),
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("ul.timeline").prepend("<img class='textarea_ajax_loading' src='img/ajax-loader.gif' style='margin: 0 auto; display: block;' />");
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('.textarea_ajax_loading').remove();
    },
    success: function () {
        //var successCount = successCount++;
        $("ul.timeline").prepend('<li class=ajax_post></li>').fadeIn();
        $("ul.timeline .ajax_post").load("ajax_post.php").fadeIn();
        //$('ul.timeline').prepend(wall_post);
        //console.log("success");
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I achieve a new post after each submission?

Thanks

Comment: Issue must be with `php` script..

Comment: My sql query is calling the latest post 
`"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");`.

Comment: Is there a way I can get each post individually from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem, but when you say "AJAX overwrites the previous posts submitted" I assume the problem is on the front-end right?

From the code I see, it might be because you prepend a new `<li class=ajax_post></li>` and then you select all the `li` with this class and load something in all of them.

If you want to load something only in the latest `li`, change the selector to

```
 $("ul.timeline .ajax_post:first").load("ajax_post.php").fadeIn();
```

to select only the first post.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted, as this is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you're inserting the new content into every child of the same class. instead of using classes you should be using IDs: declare `count` outside your Ajax call and then do the following.

```
success: function () {
  count = count++;
  $("ul.timeline").prepend('<li class=ajax_post id="post'+count+'"></li>').fadeIn();
  $("#post"+count).load("ajax_post.php").fadeIn();
```